# Where can I find some good examples of Android UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, open-source, sample

I'm quite new to the Android world, and, due to work needs, I'm trying to get in.
Whilst I'm not particularly afraid of the "thinking" code (i.e. Java), I'm a bit confused when developing the user interface.

Since I found that the simplest yet most effective way to learn something is copying from those who are the best, I'm wondering if there's some resource or something, out there, **well** done.

I mean: do you know some open source app, from which I can build my own knowledge about Android layouts? I wasn't able to do it on my own, even though I wondered quite a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: If you are using Jetpack Compose, check out my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uidesigns.withsourcecode , I have added many UI designs along with source code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1) A good summary on everything UI design in Android can be found [here](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/).

2) The best place to get started is directly from the [official website](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

And here are [relevant examples](http://www.androidauthority.com/best-designed-android-apps-238904/) that are considered as good design in Android.

Comment: First link is broken, 404 error.

Comment: [Android Design] broken link ...
(https://plus.google.com/communities/117140012142044995433)